# Excel - Display ComboBox DropDown by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a workbook to display the Combobox List Dropdown when it opens.

The combobox in the Workbook is a form control, so a shape.

Cant seem to find the associated property.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to easily trigger the drop-down to open using VBA

Comment: Ok. I understand its like saying a Combo box to look like a list box, but only when the work book opens.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using ActiveX Controls then see the below, else if you are using Form Controls then replace them with ActiveX Controls if you want the drop down to happen via code. The below code will work for both ActiveX Controls in a Form as well as Worksheet. If the Control is on a worksheet then change `ComboBox1.SetFocus` to `ComboBox1.Activate`

Two ways I can think of...

- Using a simple command

**Tried And Tested**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

- Using Sendkeys. Sendkeys are unreliable if not used properly.

**Tried And Tested**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   ComboBox1.SetFocus
   SendKeys "%{Down}"
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOTS**

[image]

Comment: Sid, they're Activex controls, not forms controls

Comment: @Kyle: The above methods will also work for ActiveX Controls in a Worksheet :) Though you will have to change `ComboBox1.SetFocus` to `ComboBox1.Activate` in the Second method.

Comment: But unless I misunderstood the question, the OP isn't using Activex controls, he's using forms controls, so might want to update your answer for dropdowns :)

Comment: My Comment was in response to your comment above ;) But yes, I have amended my answer.

Comment: I think the OP meansmeans sheet11.dropdowns(somedropdown) not a comboboxcombobox

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi, Using `SendKeys "%{Down}"` have always turned off the Num Lock on the key board. Have you ever discovered a way around that?

Comment: @Davesexcel: Happy New Year! I believe it's a bug in Microsoft VBA. The `NUMLOCK` is switched off with `SendKeys`. Of course I can always reenable the `NUMLOCK` via code `SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True` or use `GetKeyState` API to get the state of the `NUMLOCK` first so as not to mess with user's setting; i.e if it is off from beforehand then do not activate it again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had plenty of crashes with .dropdown but find some success with
the SendKeys...

Answer (score 0):

I consider  best 
UserForm combo box is as Above by Siddharth Rout
   ComboBox1.SetFocus
   SendKeys "%{Down}"

for some Combo boxes on a worksheets
   CB.DropDown   Is enough 
  .. Just as well as they have no setfocus or activate