# Focus and expand second Combobox list on Change Event on first list

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to optimise a userform from excel by focusing and expanding the second combobox when an item from the first combobox is selected.

I've tried using `.Dropdown` but I receive an error `The Object Invoked Has Disconnected from its Clients`.

The code I've written so far in the UserForm is the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "First item"
    .AddItem "second item"
End With
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox1.ListIndex
ComboBox2.Clear
Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With ComboBox2
           .AddItem "First subitem"
           .AddItem "second subitem"
           End With
    Case Is = 1
        With ComboBox2
           .AddItem "First subitem on second item"
           .AddItem "Second subitem on second item"
        End With
End Select
ComboBox2.SetFocus
ComboBox2.DropDown
End Sub
```

Also, I've written in `ThisWorkbook` section

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

The debugging highlights `UserForm1.Show` but the error only appear if I use the `ComboBox2.DropDown` line.

I know that this error is not very specific but I cannot get the code to work as expected.

Note: I simplified the code as much as I could so that the error is still there.

Comment: If you remove `ComboBox2.DropDown` you'll notice it will work. Change that line into `SendKeys "%{Down}"` and it will work.

Comment: Yes, it'll run but I want the combobox2 to expand. It will only get focused.

Comment: Have you tried the replacement code?

Comment: I didn't notice the second part of the comment when I've posted. Yes, it's working, thank you. As for what's causing the error, do you have any idea?

Comment: Not quite, but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040694/excel-display-combobox-dropdown-by-vba)

Comment: As far as I can replicate the problem, it doesn't seem to error out if CombBox1 is not populated (just change value to trigger CB2 event), so it might have something to do with how the combobox is populated?

Comment: I've tried populating the CB1 from a range, and still getting the same error. As far as I can tell from Google results you might be out of luck, it looks like a Microsoft "feature" :/

Comment: @DarXyde, try using the `.DropDown` on a combobox2.mousdown event. That works. It's puzzling indeed.

Comment: @JvdV, using `SendKeys "%{Down}"` is a nice workaround, however it disables the numlock button so I'm trying to avoid using `SendKeys` command. I wasn't able to use `Combobox1.Mousedown()`, it gives me an error `Procedure Declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name`.