# How do I keep the combobox dropdown stay visible after making a selection in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dropdown

I am writing a program that is intended to be like a nested combo box so when I make a selection, it will repopulate the combo box with the new options.  The problem happens when I have made a selection to go to a sub menu, it will then minimize the dropdown list of the combo box, and then I have to click the arrow to show the results.  My goal is to be able to keep the dropbox open once I click for a sub menu so I don't have to keep reopening it.

Here is some sample data.  It starts at A1
|MAIN_|HELLO_|GOODBYE_|I LOVE YOU_|IM HUNGRY_
|-|-|-|-|-|
hello_|bonjour|au revior|je t'aime|j'ai faim
goodbye_|hola|adios|te quiero|tengo hambre
I love you_|ni hao|zai jian|wo ai ni|wo e le
im hungry_|MAIN_|MAIN_|MAIN_|MAIN_

The code is intended to see the underscore as a menu and then search along row 1 for that text and then clear the combobox of the old column, and add the contents of the new column as the combobox choices.

i have the following events:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
 
Dim myArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim mystr As String
 
    mystr = ComboBox1.Value
    'puts the data above into an array, so everything is done with data, not cells

    myArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
   
    ComboBox1.Clear
 
    'Checks if this is a sub menu, as distinguished by underscore at the end of the text
    If Right(mystr, 1) = "_" Then

        'If it is a submenu, it must go through each of the columns of the array
        For j = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

            'The value on row one of the current column is compared with the value that the user clicked on the combobox
            If myArr(j, 1) = mystr Then

                isfound = True
                'each of the items on the column should be added to the combobox
                For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

                    'the array will be jagged when I am using real data, so no empty strings should be entered into the combobox
                    If Not Len(myArr(i, j)) = 0 Then

                        ComboBox1.AddItem myArr(i, j)
                    End If
                Next i
 
            End If
        Next j
 
    Else
        'I am using debug.print for now, but later, this will populate to a textbox
        Debug.Print mystr

        'This restores the combo box to all values in column 1
        For k = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

            If Not Len(myArr(k, 1)) = 0 Then
                ComboBox1.AddItem myArr(k, 1)
            End If
        Next k
    End If

    'this is basically the problem.  the line below works when I step through, but then when it reaches "End Sub", the dropdown disappears
    ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub 'Once end sub is processed, all the submenu values stay as they should, but the combobox minimizes.  i need it to stay dropped down.


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'this code basically puts all the values in column A as the initial combo list, which serves as the main menu
Dim myArr As Variant, i As Integer

    myArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
   
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        If Not Len(myArr(i, 1)) = 0 Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem myArr(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040694/excel-display-combobox-dropdown-by-vba

Comment: Thank you!  the ComboBox1.SetFocus; SendKeys "%{Down}" solution seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox1.SetFocus
SendKeys "%{Down}"